# How to contact a user

Tags: discussion

How do I contact and respond to someone who answers a post? someone answered my post and I cannot find a reply to post section anywhere.

Comment: That's not how Stack Exchange sites, like this one, operate. Stack Exchange sites are not "discussion forums" like you may be used to. Stack Exchange is about direct answers to direct questions and not continuous back and forth discussions between users. There is no "reply" button anywhere.

Comment: So does that mean I cannot show the file to get an answer?

Comment: You can always edit the question to include images. We don't encourage the sharing of working files (.psd, .ai, etc) though. If you don't have enough rep to include images, then just include a link, some other user will convert it to an inline image for you.

Comment: Ok, understood, so can I include an email to have someone contact me directly. I keep seeing a message saying I need 300 points or something like that. Can I hire an svg or ai tech?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(Moved from Comments)</sup>

That's not how Stack Exchange sites, like this one, operate. Stack Exchange sites are *not* "discussion forums" like you may be accustomed to.

Stack Exchange is about **direct answers to direct questions** and not continuous back and forth discussions between users. There is no "reply" button anywhere.

Stack Exchange, as a whole, does not support direct emails between users - there's no method to share email addresses or direct messages. Any posting of an email address will most likely be removed. In addition, GraphicDesign.SE is not a "job board". Any request to hire someone will be closed. Users are here to help others, not get employed. You may find it beneficial to visit the [Help Center](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help).

To be blunt...

Users here are not expecting, nor do they desire, the direct contact of anyone asking them to help with their *specific* project. Users would quickly be overwhelmed by such requests.

Users are here to help in a *general* manner and answer questions that are beneficial to *anyone* facing a similar problem, now and in the future. StackExchange sites are about helping *everyone*, not only a user posting a question.

It is understandable that your project is important to you. If you feel the need to hire someone to see it completed, Stack Exchange is not the place to find such assistance.

If you merely want to discuss aspects of your project or seek advice before venturing out to find someone to hire, then the [Chat system](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), where you can interact in a live back and forth manner with other users, may be helpful.

In short, users are here to **help**, not find projects/jobs.